# Issue with assigning enum value

Tags: c#, .net, enums, enumeration

I have an enum -

```
public enum EnumA
{
   All, A, B, C, D, E, F
}
```

I am using this enum into another class

```
public class ClassB
{
     public string[] createdOn { get; set; }
     public EnumA[] EnumA { get; set; }
}
```

I am using this ClassB in some other method –

```
public void MethodC(ClassB classB, int userId)
{
         // Now I need to check if classB.EnumA’s Count() is zero or not. If zero then I need to assign classB.ClassA[] with A, B, C, D, E, F

        // For that I have tried this –

    int index = 0;
    foreach(ClassA enumA in (ClassA[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumA)))
    {
        classB. EnumA[index++] = enumA;
    }
}
```

This throws `‘Index out of the bounds error’`.

Any help where I am going wrong?

**EDIT - I :** ClassA changed to EnumA

Comment: You never assigned a value to the `ClassA` property in `ClassB`. it is always null in your example code. You need to do something like `classB.ClassA = new ClassA[7];` somewhere. Also, you should consider renaming your types -- they are highly confusing :-)

Comment: also, what exactly is the actual problem you are trying to solve/model?

Comment: Your enum definition looks broken to start with - it sounds like it should be a Flags enum with appropriate values, e.g. `None = 0, A = 1, B = 2, C = 4, D = 8, E = 16, F = 32, All = A | B | C | D | E | F`

Comment: Change the name of your enum. An enum named class is *very* confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have to instantiate the `EnumA` property from `ClassB` in your method:

```
EnumA[] values = (EnumA[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumA));

classB.EnumA = new EnumA[values.Length];
int index = 0;
foreach (EnumA enumA in values)
{
    classB.EnumA[index++] = enumA;
}
```

But actually, your problem has a much easier solution, as suggested by Trevor: just assign it directly:

```
classB.EnumA = (EnumA[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumA));
```

Comment: Why not just use `classB.ClassA = (ClassA[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(ClassA));`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman & Trevor - The above mentioned solution works fine for me, but how am I supposed to assign all values from the enum except 'All' ?

Comment: Check with an `if` statement on the value.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are immutable structures. You can not change the arrays's size if it is already allocated. Instead of that you must create new array with new size.

Look at this code:

```
public void MethodC(ClassB classB, int userId)
{
    int index = 0;
    classB.ClassA = new ClassA[(ClassA[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(ClassA)).Length];
    foreach(ClassA classA in (ClassA[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(ClassA)))
    {
        classB. ClassA [index++] = classA;
    }
}
```